# Get HTTP Error Response body using the DownloadManager

Tags: android

I'm using the built-in DownloadManager for downloading large files

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

The server may reply with 4xx status and it includes some extra info of the error in its response body.

Is there a way to get this response body using the DownloadManager?

edit: I want to basically emulate the getErrorStream of HttpURLConnection class

Comment: does COLUMN_LOCAL_URI contain anything ?

Comment: then i would guess the answer is no. The COLUMN_REASON contains stuff like "Page not found" or "invalid request", but not the actual body. Do you actually depend on the error body? Isn't the code sufficient?

Comment: the answer seems no indeed. and no, I don't "depend" on the error body but it contains some info that might be useful for the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be just NO.

The only info we can get about the result of a Download is from the COLUMN_* values and there is nothing there to get the error body.

Comment: Did you get anything on the same? Having same issue.